# Something like IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, but only for keys (value is not needed) in .NET?

Tags: .net, collections

Is there something in .Net that allows storing/retrieving/contains keys without values?
I can use `Dictionary<string, string>` and always store `String.Empty` as value, but maybe there is some better solution?

Comment: You mean something like a `List<object>`?

Comment: Why can't you use a List<T>?  Are you looking for a collection without dupes?

Comment: @FlyingStreudel yes, but I need to test if key exists in the list.

Comment: @Will unfortunately elements of List<T> can be accessed by index and not by key. Thanks.

Comment: @This lol that makes no sense, since all you're storing is a string.  I think you need to rethink your understanding of what your collection needs to do.

Comment: @Will maybe for the sake of an example string was left there???

Comment: @This what is I don't even language barrier much?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) class, it's meant to store distinct values in a set.

The main difference between that and an [`IDictionary{TKey, TValue}`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx) (aside from the fact that it doesn't store values) is that you can add the same value to the `HashSet<T>` and if it already exists it does not throw an exception (when you try and call the [`Add` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005.aspx) on it, as opposed to the [`Add` method on `IDictionary{TKey, TValue}`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy7xta5e.aspx), which will throw an `ArgumentException` if the item exists in the dictionary already.

Answer (score 3):

Try [`Hashset<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) if you're using .NET 3.5 or above.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET 3.5 you can go with the HashSet class. If not then you have to create your own generic class (maybe inherit from `List<>` and do the checks).

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx)

Here's the relevant excerpt from MSDN:

> The HashSet<T> class provides
>   high-performance set operations. A set
>   is a collection that contains no
>   duplicate elements, and whose elements
>   are in no particular order.
>
> The capacity of a HashSet<T> object is
>   the number of elements that the object
>   can hold. A HashSet<T> object's
>   capacity automatically increases as
>   elements are added to the object.
>
> Starting with the .NET Framework
>   version 4, the HashSet<T> class
>   implements the ISet<T> interface.

Answer (score 0):

`List<T>` has a [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) method to test if a certain element exists in the list but `HashSet` as other suggests would work and is probably faster as it cannot contain duplicates. `List<T>` can have duplicate values.